# Angular Reactive Form How to Store JSON data?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

how to store json data with angular reactive form , in form control .

for example

```
json coming from server  = [{
ctrlname : controlName1,
type : "Link",
unit:"M"

},{
ctrlname : controlName2,
type : "Date",
unit:"L"

}]
```

// making FormGroup

```
  let a = new formGroup({
    controlName1 : new FormControl(''),
    controlName2 : new FormControl(''),
    })
```

i want to store **type,unit** property also with formcontrol so how can i do it ? when making formgroup with formcontrol?

**so when i get the value of formcontrol like this.myformgroup.controls['controlName1'] so i can get the unit and type also from this ? so how to store unit and type json while making the formcontrol**

Comment: Define "store"...

Comment: @Brandon updated the question please check

Comment: Provided the "ctrlname" value is unique, you could use `.find()` on the array of values to get the one that corresponds to the control name. From there you could maintain your own array of objects that has the form input value plus the other two values.

Comment: @Brandon yes i am doing the same method but it would be more optimised and good if we can store data with formcontrol as i have to use .find method everywhere . so is there anyway that we can store json data with formcontrol ?

Comment: The FormControl doesn't have any additional properties you could bind the extra values to.

Comment: but it makes the reactiveform use expensive and we need to filter the array  again  and again whenever we need the value. is thier any alternative approach i can follow ? @Brandon

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The FormControl only accepts the value you want to bind to it for editing. It's not computationally expensive if you're looking up a value by an index, that's O(1)

Comment: What you could do that would be more efficient is to store the extra values in an ViewModel property that is an object using the control name as the key. That will give you constant-time lookups to get the values for each input. It's as efficient as it can get.

Comment: @Brandon can you give a pseudocode that would be more clear

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments, one way you can do this is to store these extra pieces of data in a ViewModel property and update them as your inputs change...

```
interface IFormData: {
  [controlName: string]: {
    value?: string;
    type?: string;
    unit?: string;
  }
}

@Component(...)
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  control1Subscription: Subscription;
  data: IFormData = {
    controlName1: {},
    controlName2: {},
  };
  form: FormGroup;
  serviceData;

  constructor (
    formBuilder: FormBuilder;
  )

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // get your service data here. We'll assume it's available

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      controlName1 : new FormControl(''),
      controlName2 : new FormControl(''),
    });

    // every time the input value changes, get the associated values
    this.control1Subscription = this.form.get('controlName1').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        const data = this.serviceData.find(data => data.ctrlname === 'controlName1');
        this.data['controlName1'].value = value;
        this.data['controlName1'].type = data.type;
        this.data['controlName1'].unit = data.unit;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.control1Subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

You could create these input value changes subscriptions in a loop, substituting the hard-coded `ctrlname` values for the values in your data, making it scale to suit your needs.

Later, when you need to look up each set of values because you're able to reference each object by key, it's constant-time lookup and therefore as fast as you can retrieve them.

Comment: the subscription will run wehever the valuechanges of the controller for example if its textbox so whever i will write a charachter the subscription will work that will make performance poor

Comment: You can always add pipes to suit your needs. You asked for pseudocode, not an exact, perfectly performance-tuned solution. Unless you're talking about hundreds of fields, performance isn't going to be that poor. A person can only type in one field at a time.

Comment: i think making the object map on ngoninit would be efficient as mapping would run one time and then we can easily get the value using just they key . is this approach correct ?

Comment: Well, you never stated when you needed to associate these values. If you only need them at the end of your process, sure. If you need them any time the value changes, you'd need my approach.

Comment: but why are you updating the values of unit and type again and again when a value is changed ? if its set one time it will not be changed again and again so why setting it ? Thats my question !

Comment: Look, it's just sample code. It's not meant to be copy-pasted out. It sounds like your data that's coming back from your service already has the form element names as the keys to the objects? If that's the case, use that as start of the ViewModel property, and add a new property to it to hold your form value. Look up the value by the form control name (key) and set the value, leaving all of the other values alone.

Comment: If you want an exact, production ready answer, you need to provide every detail necessary in your question to produce such an answer.